# Pulumi Project Folder structure

Tags: pulumi, pulumi-azure

I am new to the pulumi and planning to create an IaC project in pulumi.

Bit confused about the project structure of pulumi. I was planning to create classes based on SOLID principles - however, when looking at the project structure listed on pulumi site or examples on github, it appears that I need to call.

Stack: ComponentResource class.

I was planning to create multiple classes inheriting from the stack and calling it from the Program's main course.

```
   public static class Program
        {
            static Task<int> Main() => Deployment.RunAsync<Stack>();
    }
```

Q1 Is it possible/good practice to bifurcate in multiple stack classes?
Q2 If I am creating two projects, one for IaC and the other for Function deployment. HOw can I set dependency between tasks as the Inc environment needs to be spun up first?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks got the answer to the question. I can create the stack class and classes related to DNS, app service plan, function app, etc., with output variable and need to consume all these classes under stack class by creating its instance.